# How do I use survival trail scrolls?

Tags: naruto-online

The survival trial had an update with 4.0 and introduced new scrolls to go along with survival trial. I figured out how to use the difficulty switching scroll, but not the other 2.

Refresh scroll just sits in my inventory and doesn't do anything when I click it. It's supposed to allow me to refresh the trial but nothing happens.

The growth scroll is the most common and it's supposed to grant you 10 points to your total score, but I can't seem to use it. I click on the points and the scroll itself in my inventory and nothing seems to happen.

Is there somewhere where I have to activate these scrolls...? How do I use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. You can't use the growth scrolls on Ultimate/Elite difficulty, you have to use them on the lesser ones. You can activate the scrolls by clicking the orange circle with the + sign in the middle of it, to the right of the currect trial score. This circle disappears in the Ultimate/Elite levels.